# How to use zsh in flatpak vscode

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, zsh

I have `Visual Studio Code` installed in flatpak, I run it with:

> flatpak run --command=sh com.visualstudio.code

I want to change the shell to `zsh`, but I can't find how to, I tried multiple thing in my `settings.json`:

```
...
"terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux": ["--host", "run", "env", "TERM=xterm-256color", "zsh"],
...
```

And

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "bash": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
        "args": ["--host", "--env=TERM=xterm-256color", "zsh"]
    }
}
```

None works.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I personally got it working on my vscode, FYI **terminal.integrated.shell.linux** was deprecated:

```
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "bash": {
      "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
      "args": ["--host", "--env=TERM=xterm-256color", "zsh"]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. The same works in phpstorm - use "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn --host zsh" as shell path in Settings->Tools->Terminal

Comment: "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn --host zsh" works well also for Phpstorm when installed via Flatpak

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `terminal.integrated.shell.linux` is deprecated. Instead, you should create your own terminal profile:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "zsh": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
        "args": ["--host", "--env=TERM=xterm-256color", "zsh"],
        "overrideName": true,
    }
},
```

and set that as the default:

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
```

The line `"overrideName": true` is required for the terminal name to show up as `zsh` in the list of open terminal windows. Otherwise it is displayed as `flatpak-spawn`.

Comment: working for me. ubuntu 22.04